# Is there a maximum amount of data that can be read during a Fortran namelist read?

Tags: string, io, fortran, intel-fortran

Is there a maximum amount of data that can be read in a namelist read using Intel Visual Fortran?

I'm interested to know total, but more specifically for an individual field.

I can't seem to find anything on it anywhere, but it seems to be crashing at around a 2,500 character array. I'm trying to put it into a 3,000 character array.

The data is on one line too if that could be an issue.

Comment: If there is such a limit, it will be processor dependent. You must specify your compiler, otherwise there can't be any definitive answer. If you have a crash with your program, prepare a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I did specify the compiler unless you are looking for Intel Visual Fortran 13.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Intel Fortran this is documented under the topic "Compiler Limits". The maximum size of a character value read in during list-directed and NAMELIST I/O is 2048. The variable itself may be longer.